# Storing XY coordinates in ArcGIS table as decimal numbers without losing zeros at the end

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table

I have created an ArcGIS table that contains coordinates as decimal numbers (float) with precision of 4 digits. The problem is that the zeros at the end of numbers in ArcGIS disappear, so I need a solution of how to keep/add zeros at the end of coordinates that have zeros at the end- for example, I need '64.12' to be stored like '64.1200'.

Comment: See the answers to this question: [Nicest way to pad zeroes to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to better define "ArcGIS table" by specifying the data storage format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot show the '00' value in float number. You need to convert the value to string by adding `Text field` then use the following formula in field calculator:

1. Select `Python` parser, and write
2. `str(!Field_Name!) + "00"`

The value will be like this "18.4600"

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, there is an option to set zeros padding.

1. Open Attribute Table
2. Right-click on your subject Field header and select Properties to call up *Field Properties* dialog.
3. There is a three dots [...] button to set Number format. Click on this button and bring *Number Format* dialog.
4. There you have **Pad with zeros** option. Check on it and press OK button to close the dialog window.